# Проблема с использование функции в двух обьектах C++

Tags: c++

При использовании одной в двух обьектах работает только один, второй отказывается.
Игра Кораблики , функция начинает игру и используется в двух  обьектах , в первом засчитывает , а во втором ничего не работает.

```
void Plansza::startgame()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        matrix2[i][j] = '.';
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        matrix3[i][j] = '.';
    }
}
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
TryAgain: cout << "Your choice: ";
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    if (matrix1[x][y] == 'O') {
        cout << "Succes!" << endl;
        count1 = count1 + 1;
        draw_enemy1(x, y);
        if (count1 == 20) {
            cout << "You won!";
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        goto TryAgain;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Missed" << endl;
        draw_enemy1(x, y);
    }
TryAgain1: cout << "Enemy choice: ";
    int x1, y1;
    cin >> x1 >> y1;
    if (matrix[x1][y1] == 'O') {
        cout << "Succes!" << endl;
        count2 = count2 + 1;
        draw_enemy(x1, y1);
        if (count2 == 20) {
            cout << "You won!";
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        goto TryAgain1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Missed" << endl;
        draw_enemy(x1, y1);
    }

    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Вот так вот использую это в обьектах

```
yourShips.startgame();
enemyShips.startgame();
```

Comment: *"У меня что-то болит!" - "Выпейте каких-то лекарств!"* Что именно не работает? Как? Какие классы? Как определены? Что такое ваши `matrix2`, `matrix3`? И еще много вопросов. И ответ пока один - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вторая заработает, после того как будет закончена первая игра

Comment: не хотите головной боли, не пользуйтесь   goto

Comment: Не работает эта функция в обьекте enemyShips, в обьекте yourShips, обьекты идентичны, с классами все нормально , проблема в самой функции
matrix - это поля которые полностью заполнены точками и меняются при попадании

Comment: @ValeraKvip , а как можно исправить , что бы они работали по очереди , по попаданиям то есть ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , а как его в данном случае можно заменить?

Comment: @ValeraKvip ???

Comment: точного ответа не дам, потому что тут не ясно что вы пытаетесь делать, зачем вам 4 матрицы, и  неясно функция draw_enemy1 и draw_enemy это разные функции или просто опечатка?  Могу только сказать, что  нужно убрать из кода   команду    system("pause"); потому что  именно она и не дает вам вводить значения, кроме этого  неясно что введете(вполне можете выйти за пределы массива.

Comment: к тому же циклы перехода пока не закончатся, функция не закончит свою работу. Пока она не завершит работу, следующая инструкция не выполнится(в данном случаи его вызов для другого обьекта)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , 4 матрицы для того что бы 2 из них для заполнения кораблями , а 2 для того что бы я когда стрелял , то видел куда стрельнул
draw_enemy рисует матрицы ,draw_enemy1 - рисует матрицы для другого игрока

Comment: @OnlyWeb, ладно, посмотрите пример  ответа, но  пока неизвестны все детали, точного ответа не гарантирую. Но если вы пишете классы и функции, то старайтесь их писать так, чтобы программа не повторяла один и тот же код и работала только с обьектами. и функциями.

Answer (score 0):

Не смогу дать точного ответа, так как мное тут не ясно. 
В принципе, функции  `draw_enemy` не должно интересовать какой обьект рисует(рассмотрите вариант передачи в функцию ссыльку на игрока). К тому же, лучше, если эта функция будет членом класса, чей обьект рисуете... Предположительно вы хотите следующее:

```
//эту функцию можете сделать закрытым членом класса
void your_code(char* matrix, const size_t col)
{
    int count = 0;    
    int x, y;
    while (matrix[x * col + y] == 'O') {
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << "Succes!" << endl;
        ++count;
        draw_enemy1(x, y);
        if (count == 20) {
            cout << "You won!";
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Missed" << endl;
    draw_enemy1(x, y);
    cout << endl;
}
void Plansza::startgame()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            matrix2[i][j] = '.';
            matrix3[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        your_code(matrix1[0], 10);
        your_code(matrix[0], 10);
    }
}
```

В вашем коде оператор безусловного перехода `goto`  и  команда `system("pause");`(Это приостановка выполнения пакетного файла, что в вашей функции абсолютно никчему) вполне могут помешать завершению выполнения функции, а пока она не завершит свою работу, для второго обьекта не вызовится, поскольку ни одна инструкция не выполнится. Вот и получается, что до второго обьекта дело не доходит. И всегда старайтесь циклы писать с предусловием типа, например,  `while (условие) { ... }`

Comment: А можно пожалуйста немного разьяснить комментариями? 
while (matrix[x * col + y] == 'O')  - не очень понимаю что делает эта строка

Comment: двумерный массив можно передать(рассмотреть) как одномерный массив.    Так как `matrix` является указателем, то ему можно присвоить указатель на первый элемент(`matrix1[0]`  это то же самое, что и `&matrix1[0][0]`). Так как в двумерных массивах элементы распологаются строка за  строкой, то получить элемент `matrix1[x][y] ` через этот указатель можно умножив  индекс строки на количество столбцов и добавлять индекс столбца `matrix[x * col + y] ` Читайте статьи(вопросы ) про то, как передать в функцию двумерный массив

Comment: Числа вводятся , но потом просто ничего не происходит , хотя должно выводить матрицу , возможно из за того что у меня используется статическая матрица , а тут все сделано динамически , может быть в этом проблема?

Comment: я же не знаю что вы делаете, я же написал, что  "Предположительно... ". Я не написал код, чтобы вы взяли и по нему работали, а чтобы понели какой логикой писать его.  Можете считать это псевдокодом, я лишь ответил на вашу просьбу помочь понять почему функция не вызывается для второго обьекта и как убрать goto из кода И давайте закончим это обсуждение. Я попытался помочь, но видимо  не получилось...

Comment: А можно ли как нибудь исправить мой участок кода?
Я вызываю одну и ту же функцию для разных обьектов и не срабатывают именно массивы matrix для второго обьекта , а для первого работают
В чем тут может быть проблема?